# Iterating over elements in a nested list

Tags: ruby, list, iteration

To iterate through the elements in a single dimensional array, I can use

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
array.each { |x| puts x }
```

Is there any way I to do this for a nested list or a two dimensional array? In this code:

```
two_d_array = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
two_d_array.each{|array| puts array}
```

I wish to get `[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]` so that I can access each element of the list separately and do some operation on it such as `array[1] = "new_value"`, but it gives   `123456` I want to avoid using [matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.htmlhttp://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the `each` block *does* behave in the way you expect, but the `puts` command makes it look as though the array has been pre-flattened.  If you add an `inspect`, this becomes clear:

```
>> two_d_array.each{|array| puts array.inspect}
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
```

So the `array` variable in each iteration will be the nested array element.

Comment: Or he can also use pp instead of puts

Comment: I tried two_d_array.each{|array| funct(array)} but the funct doesn't receive individual lists as arguments.

Comment: I'm a little confused - so what is happening to make you say that `funct` is not receiving an array?  Might help to edit the question and include a fuller example to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @primpop did you get this working in the end?  If so please consider marking this answer as accepted!

Comment: @JonM I changed'funct' around a bit from the initial one I showed. Anyways, your answer helped in sorting out the problem. Thanks.